# Fixing date format in R

Tags: r, date, format

I have three data tables in R. Each one has a date column. The tables are `vix_data,gold_ohlc_data,btc_ohlc_data`. They are formatted as follows:

```
head(vix_data$Date)
[1] 1/2/04 1/5/04 1/6/04 1/7/04 1/8/04 1/9/04
3435 Levels: 1/10/05 1/10/06 1/10/07 1/10/08 1/10/11 ... 9/9/16

head(gold_ohlc_data$date)
[1] 8/23/17 8/22/17 8/21/17 8/18/17 8/17/17 8/16/17
2519 Levels: 1/10/08 1/10/11 1/10/12 1/10/13 1/10/14 ... 9/9/16

head(btc_ohlc_data$Date)
[1] "2017-08-23" "2017-08-22" "2017-08-21" "2017-08-20" "2017-08-19"
[6] "2017-08-18"
```

How can I change the date column in the `vix_data` and `gold_ohlc_data` tables to match the `btc_ohlc_data` format? I have tried several methods, for example using `as.Date` to transform each column- but this usually messes up the values and inserts a lot of N/A's

Comment: In `vix_data$Date`, which one is day and which one is month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use functions from the package `lubridate`. The users need to know which one is day and which one is month to select the right function to use, such as `dmy` or `mdy`

```
# Load package
library(lubridate)

# Create example string
date1 <- c("1/2/04", "1/5/04", "1/6/04", "1/7/04", "1/8/04", "1/9/04")
date2 <- c("8/23/17", "8/22/17", "8/21/17", "8/18/17", "8/17/17", "8/16/17")

# Convert to date class
dmy(date1)
# [1] "2004-02-01" "2004-05-01" "2004-06-01" "2004-07-01" "2004-08-01" "2004-09-01"
mdy(date1)
# [1] "2004-01-02" "2004-01-05" "2004-01-06" "2004-01-07" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-09"
mdy(date2)
# [1] "2017-08-23" "2017-08-22" "2017-08-21" "2017-08-18" "2017-08-17" "2017-08-16"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the package [lubridate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/vignettes/lubridate.html). `lubridate::dmy()` and `ymd()` should handle this just fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data are read in as factors, so first you'll have to change them to characters.  Then after that you can convert it to a date and specify the input format where `%m` represents the numerical month, `%d` represents the day, and `%y` represents the 2-digit year.

```
x <- c('1/2/04', '1/5/04', '1/6/04', '1/7/04', '1/8/04', '1/9/04')
y <- as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%y")
y
[1] "2004-01-02" "2004-01-05" "2004-01-06" "2004-01-07" "2004-01-08"
[6] "2004-01-09"
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're specifying `as.Date` correctly? For example, do you have `%y`, instead of `%Y`?

I did the following and it worked:

```
> vix <- c("1/2/04", "1/5/04", "1/6/04", "1/7/04", "1/8/04", "1/9/04")
> vix<- as.factor(vix)
> vix
[1] 1/2/04 1/5/04 1/6/04 1/7/04 1/8/04 1/9/04
Levels: 1/2/04 1/5/04 1/6/04 1/7/04 1/8/04 1/9/04
> as.Date(vix, "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "2004-01-02" "2004-01-05" "2004-01-06" "2004-01-07" "2004-01-08" "2004-01-09"
```